# Windows does not boot after switching off with drained battery

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have a Dell XPS 15 laptop running Windows 8. When I try to boot, Windows runs automatic repair, which fails saying it can not resolve the issue.

I opened the command prompt under the repair tool and ran `bootrec /fixmbr`, which worked just fine. The PC passes a chkdsk.

Comment: How were you able to do all that if it couldn't boot?

Comment: i have cmd prompt in advanced troubleshoot

Comment: If none of the recovery tools can fix the problem then there isn't really another solution except to install Windows 8 again.

Comment: still i cannot upgrade or restore using usb stick

Comment: i solved it by running disk fragmentation through command prompt and everything got cleared and started running just fine.
but i don't know why?